# Concerns with Global Choice vs Ordinary Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, philosophy

I know that the axiom of choice is widely accepted by mathematicians nowadays, despite early worries about it. What is the sociological status of the axiom of *global* choice these days? And are there distinctive mathematical and/or philosophical concerns about it that don't apply to the ordinary axiom of choice?

Comment: ZFC + Global choice is conservative over ZFC, so its (first-order) consequence is exactly the same as that of ZFC. Thus we may think opposing a consequence of the global choice is the same as opposing that of the usual choice.